# Tagit behaving strangely in our Angular JS application

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tag-it

We are using the JQuery Tagit library in our Angular JS application.  This requires a bit of finessing, for example making manual calls to `$scope.$apply()` to make sure the Tagit widget UI is updated at certain times.  However, we have encountered a problem which we don't have the expertise to solve.  We have two Tagit boxes on a single page, one of which appears in a modal popup (though still on the same page).  Here is the HTML code for these two Tagit elements:

```
<ul id="mailShareTags" tag-it>   <!-- for the main page -->
<ul id="mailIdTags" tag-it>      <!-- for the modal -->
```

They share the same directive, but the IDs are different.

**The problem:**

What we are observing is that if a user removes entries from the Tagit in the modal, the entries are actually being removed from *both* underlying models.  In other words, if we inspect the currently assigned tags via the following code, we observe that removing a tag from one Tagit removes it from *both* models:

```
// removing from the modal also removes it here
$scope.currentIds = $("#mailShareTags").tagit("assignedTags");
```

The problem continues further.  When our JavaScript code does cleanup on the main Tagit via:

```
tagit("removeTagByLabel", some_id);
```

the tags which were removed in the modal still appear in the UI.  It seems that even those these tags were removed from the modal, a digest never took place to let the UI know that these tags were removed (and ideally we don't even want these tags removed in the first place).

I would be more than happy to offer any information you might require.  Any and all insights would be welcome here.

Comment: can you setup a plunk or something?

Comment: @HFA Believe it or not we just found a workaround.  I will post an answer shortly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, we tried something on a lark and it happened to resolve the problem, or at least the error visible in the UI.  Instead of using:

```
$("#mailShareTags").tagit("removeTagByLabel", some_id);
```

for each tag in the widget, we instead made a single call to:

```
$("#mailShareTags").tagit("removeAll");
```

This removed all elements from the Tagit as well as cleaned up the UI in our case.

If anyone encounters an issue with synching a Tagit's model with what the UI shows when removing all tags, consider using `tagit("remoteAll")` instead of removing tags individually.